# Building a process Watchdog

Tags: process-management, watchdog

I intend to write a process watchdog that runs out of cron or similar that watches all of the core processes denoting things like run state, VMstat, Inet operations and reports it to a file or external host.

If a process dies that is deemed core it restarts it. Is an already written watchdog existent that can address my needs?

Comment: See: `upstart`, `systemd`, and `supervisord`.

Comment: I think Zabbix could help you. It's used for monitoring and can trigger alerts and takes actions if you configure it to do so. It's quite a big thing though...

Comment: @Rohan `systemd` and `supervisord` have decent re-spawning capabilities (with logs) but don't report resource utilization by themselves. You could add it to a cgroup and then just write a cronjob that emails the stats for the cgroup wherever you're wanting it to go, though.

Comment: @Rohan & @jordanm, I have tried with `supervisord`, not able to controll properly. Here is my question-->http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358522/supervisor-as-watchdog-for-various-services